# jstree stuck on loading?

Tags: jstree

Using the following code, jstree gets stuck on loading.

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>No title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme2/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout-default-latest.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></script>  



$("#treeFile").jstree({ "themes" :  { 
                        "theme" : "default", 
                        "dots" : false, 
                        "icons" : false 
                    },
            "plugins" : ["themes", "treeFile"]
});
```

Interesting, if the change value of false to fales, it works but unable to give the dots and icons names a real false value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#treeFile").jstree({ "themes" :  { 
                    "theme" : "default", 
                    "dots" : "false", 
                    "icons" : "false" 
                },
        "plugins" : ["themes", "treeFile"]
});
```

Comment: did not work but what is weird, the false word shows up as a text value and not as a variable

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the datasource.

```
    "json_data" : {
             {
                 "data" : "Node 1",
                 "children" :[],
                 "state" : "open"
             },
             {
                 "data" : "Node 2",
                 "children" :[],
                 "state" : "open"
             },
             {
                 "data" : "Node 3",
                 "children" :[],
                 "state" : "open"
             }
        },
        "themes" : {"theme" : "classic"},
        "plugins" : ["themes", "json_data"]
}
```